# How to Stop Squeaking of a Lofted Bed

Tags: framing, paint, metal, bedroom, frame

The bed in question is a Viv Rae Nadia.

I assembled the bed, put the mattress on, and stored several things on the included shelves. Any sort of movement makes a squeaking noise through some parts of the frame. What can I do to dampen this noise?

Answer (score 1):

First try tightening the hardware. If you can isolate the offending joint disassemble it. Rub some candlewax on both sides then reassemble it.